Enumerating externalItem objects in Microsoft Graph
I have an external connection for Microsoft Graph into which I'm pushing externalItem entities generated from a documentation site (it's not crawlable, hence why I'm pushing items in rather than letting MS Graph crawl). I'd like to also list the externalItem objects that are currently stored so that I can delete any that are obsolete, but I'm not seeing any way to do that. I tried just doing a GET /external/connections/<id>/items/, but that doesn't work. I want to avoid having to maintain an artifact listing what was previously pushed into the graph because of the risk of it drifting from the source of truth.
How can one list externalItem objects for an external connection in Microsoft Graph?

I'm think that the concept behind the external items doesn't allow you to retrieve the collection of items. You can get only an item by id.
GET /v1.0/external/connections/{connection_id}/items/{item_id}

As a workaround, you can use Search API which allows you to query all items, but you will need to enumerate all pages, because it returns only 500 items per request
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/search/query

{
    "requests": [
        {
            "entityTypes": [
                "externalItem"
            ],
            "contentSources": [
                "/external/connections/{connector_id}"
            ],
            "query": {
                "queryString": "*"
            },
            "from": 0,
            "size": 500,
            "fields": [
                "prop1",
                "prop2"
            ]
        }
    ]
}

The queryString with value * will ensure that all items are returned.
Check the property moreResultsAvailable in the response. Increment from by size until moreResultsAvailable is true.
But I can't confirm that the response will contain item's id you need to be able to delete the external item.
So, maybe at the end, you will have to store items ids somewhere. I would personally add extra property into the connection schema for that purpose.

Great! I had tried this but am getting a 401 response using a client secret value. It seems like the token doesn't have permissions. I'm just using the .default scope when getting my token. Do you happen to know if there's something else required for that?

Looks like the admins were able to add some permissions which get me past the 401. Thank you!

Spoke too soon. "Application permission is only supported for the following entity types:site, list, listItem, drive and driveItem." They only let users search, not the apps that populated the data?

Looks like, the doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/search-concept-custom-types doesn't mention if searching for external items supports application permissions. In that case, you really need to store external item's id and access items one by one via /external/connections/{connection_id}/items/{item_id}.
